# report viewer is blank

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer

work with visual studio 2012. I need to load my report viewer  inside a div in my web page. But it would be blank. It works fine a separate web page alone, but when I want to load it inside a section inside my content page, it is blank. The part of my code which works with report viewer:

```
          // add a div dynamically
        HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div.Attributes.Add("id", "chart05");
        div.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        div.Attributes["class"] = "chartItem";
        sanaChartsContainer.Controls.Add(div);    
        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer viewer = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer();
        viewer.Attributes.Add("id", "ReportViewer");
        viewer.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        viewer.Attributes.Add("Font-Names", "Verdana");
        viewer.Attributes.Add("Font-Size", "8pt");
        viewer.Attributes.Add("Height", "50px");
        viewer.Attributes.Add("ProcessingMode", "Remote");
        viewer.Attributes.Add("WaitMessageFont-Name", "Verdana");
        viewer.Attributes.Add("WaitMessageFont-Size", "14pt");
        viewer.Attributes.Add("Width", "50px");
        viewer.Attributes.Add("AsyncRendering", "false");
        viewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
        viewer.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
        Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://mdb165.cbi.net/reportserver");

        viewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = baseUri;
        viewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/SanaII/report005";

        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager scriptManager = new ScriptManager();
        Page page = new Page();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();

        //div.Controls.Add(scriptManager);
        div.Controls.Add(viewer);
```

My web config is:

```
  <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">    
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also added script manager to my page, 
but report viewer is blank.

I also tried to load it directly in my content page as below shows:

but this is also doesn't work and is blank.
Please give me help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding **if(!IsPostBack)** in your Page_Load?

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SetDate();
                BindCustomerCategory();
                BindUtility();
            }

        }
```

OR if this will not work. Double check the aspx of your report page you might forgot something there..